# Strange behaviour with Plugin on Update of activity

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm creating a plugin on creating a phonecall activity to update a field in the recipients contact entities. This plugin runs on Create and on Update of a phonecall activity.

**On Create AND "new_targetfield" is null => Updates correctly**

**On Update AND "new_targetfield" not null => Updates correctly**

**On Update AND "new_targetfield" is null => Nothing happens**

I tried running the Plugin Profiler but I keep getting an error:

```
 <ErrorCode>-2147220970</ErrorCode>
 <ErrorDetails xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic
```

Here's a part of my code :

```
        IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));

        IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
        IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);

        if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") && context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity)
        {
            Entity entity = context.InputParameters["Target"] as Entity;

            if (entity.LogicalName != "phonecall")
            {
                return;
            }


            DateTime activitydate=entity.GetAttributeValue<DateTime>("actualstart");
            if (activitydate ==null && context.MessageName =="Update")
            {
                activitydate=((Entity)context.PostEntityImages["PhoneCallPostImage"]).GetAttributeValue<DateTime>("actualstart");
            }


            if (activitydate != null)
            {

                // update recipients
                EntityCollection Recipients = entity.GetAttributeValue<EntityCollection>("to");

                if (Recipients == null && context.MessageName == "Update")
                {
                    Recipients = ((Entity)context.PostEntityImages["PhoneCallPostImage"]).GetAttributeValue<EntityCollection>("to");

                }

                if (Recipients != null)
                {
                    foreach (Entity recipient in Recipients.Entities)
                    {
                        EntityReference partyId = recipient.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("partyid");

                        if (partyId != null)
                        {

                            // get recipient id
                            if (partyId.LogicalName == "contact")
                            {
                                Guid contactid = partyId.Id;

                                // update the recipient Last Contacted with Phone call date 
                                string fetch = @"<fetch version='1.0' output-format='xml-platform' mapping='logical' distinct='false'>
                                  <entity name='contact'>
                                    <attribute name='contactid' />
                                    <attribute name='new_targetfield' />
                                    <filter type='and'>
                                      <condition attribute='contactid' operator='eq' uitype='contact' value='"+contactid+@"' />
                                    </filter>
                                  </entity>
                                </fetch>";

                                EntityCollection result = service.RetrieveMultiple(new Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query.FetchExpression(fetch));
                                if (result.Entities.Count > 0)
                                {
                                    DateTime lasttouched = result.Entities[0].GetAttributeValue<DateTime>("new_targetfield");
                                    if (lasttouched != null)
                                    {
                                        if (activitydate > lasttouched)
                                        {
                                            Entity contact = new Entity();
                                            contact.LogicalName = "contact";
                                            contact.Id = contactid;
                                            contact.Attributes = new AttributeCollection();
                                            contact.Attributes.Add("new_targetfield", activitydate);

                                            service.Update(contact);
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            continue;
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        Entity contact = new Entity();
                                        contact.LogicalName = "contact";
                                        contact.Id = contactid;
                                        contact.Attributes = new AttributeCollection();
                                        contact.Attributes.Add("new_targetfield", activitydate);

                                        service.Update(contact);
                                    }



                                }

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                continue;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            continue;
                        }

                    }
                }
```

Comment: please post complete code. Can not find out whats the purpose and the context of the "continue;" statements. If plugin profiler is not working use the tracingservice to log statements (throw an error at the end of your plugin to view the tracelog). Or write to the console and see if you can find the output in the trace log on the server (make sure tracing is enabled in registry)

Comment: Have you debugged your code ?? I think its the else part hitting if lasttouched is NULL then the else part executes, the new Entity.

Comment: @salyh I guess "continue" is not of a good use here, I could simply have left it blank. That's almost my whole code, the rest of the code is separate from the logic here. I will try using tracingservice

Comment: @Dot_NETJunior Yes I've tried using the Plugin Profiler as i mentioned but it threw an exception. What you said is correct, I need to execute the else part of the code here, but it should update correctly. It updates the entity on the "Create" event but doesn't update it on "Update"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that a `DateTime` variable will never be `null` but equal to the `MinValue` of `DateTime`. That's why parts of the code weren't approached.